# Connect Nextbook next7p12 Tablet with PC

Tags: android, android-emulator

I brought Nextbook premium 7se tablet for testing the android applications. I connected with pc and switch on the debug mode in the setting but i can't able to connect with eclipse to test all my developing apps.And there is no driver software for the tablet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that there is no option to connect with eclipse. With out the Driver software we can't connect any of the device with eclipse and regarding the Nextbook even the company didn't proved and driver for windows or for debugging. So its better export the APK and install it by copying to phone memory.

Comment: That's similar to what I came across with a nextbook I have with Jellybean. Galaxy Tab 3 (jellybean) CAN connect via debugging so its not a jellybean problem.